# App.config file security in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

How to secure App.config file.  As it contains all the passwords that connections use so any body can see the data in my databases.

If we donot save the password at the time of making connection string, will it still be able to connect with the DB the same way?

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: What is a public app doing connecting directly to your database?

Comment: A client should never have direct access to your database.  Ever.  If you have a connection string etc that's worth keeping private, it should be on the server side -- cause anything in the client can, and you should assume it *will*, be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

See articles at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Depending on the nature of you app, you might also want to look at adding an intermediate service between the client and database.. google for n-tier design